# can't deploy spring war file after migrating Java JDK 1.6 to 1.8 on Apache server

Tags: apache, java-8, war

I've been working on different Spring project at work and was just notified that they were requested to upgrade java from 1.6 to 1.8

I updated my machine (localhost) and then was able to deploy the war file to my localhost without any issues but the webserver gives the status OK once uploaded but it won't deploy the file nor create the directory structure in the webapps directory.

My local server status info is as follow:
Tomcat Version: Pivotal tc Runtime 3.1.2.RELEASE/8.0.26.B.RELASE   
JVM Version: 1.8.0_66-b18 
JVM Vendor: Oracle 
OS Name: Windows 7 
OS Version: 6.1 
OS Architecture: amd64 

WebServerinfo:
Tomcat Version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.22
JVM Version: 1.8.0-b17
JVM Vendor: Oracle Corporation
OS Name: Linux
OS Version: 2.6.32.12-0.7-default
OS Infractucture: amd64

I tried looking at the different log files but couldn't find anything related to it.
What can i do to figure out what is causing the webserver not to deploy the file properly?

Thanks

Comment: I checked the catalina.log file this morning again and had an error that was regarding the javacompiler in STS that still uses skd1.6 now that i fixed this the directory is actually created as well the files but am getting the following error now

Comment: `Nov 20, 2015 12:35:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive eaf.war
Nov 20, 2015 12:35:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/eaf]]
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(Contain`